# filter results from another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have two arrays like this.

```
let emailList = [ [ 'OM Email', 'Team/Location' ],
                  [ 'email2@email.com', 'Addison' ],
                  [ 'email1@email.com', 'SouthArlington' ]]

let data = [ [ 'Addison',13373,'Addison','Office Team',4,'Jordan M','DFW','General',2,1,0,31,63,
              73 ],
             [ 'SouthArlington',13373,'SouthArlington','Office Team',4,'Jordan M','DFW','General',2,1,0,31,63,
              73 ],
```

[ 'Addison',13374,'Addison','Office Team3',5,'Jordan M','DFW','General',2,1,0,31,63,
73 ]
]

id like to filter through the `data` array and see if it finds a location from the `emailList`.  (The position from the `data` is at `2` ) if it does find a location from the data, pop it and create a new array each time for each location.

What I am trying to do is I am filtering through a google-sheets for when a certain column equals something.  That is currently working, thats the information from the `data` array.  What I am trying to do is send a notification to each office from the emailList along with their respectives rows.

this is how iam filtering `data` from the google-sheet doc

```
  let data = thisSpreadsheet.filter(function (row,index) {
      return row[11] >= 30 
  });
```

if i filter again on data, i get the results but i need it for each matching office.

```
let locationList  = data.filter(function(location){

    return location[2] === emailList[1][1]

})
```

Expected:

```
    let Addison = [[ 'Addison',13373,'Addison','Office Team',4,'Jordan M','DFW','General',2,1,0,31,63,
                  73 ],
[ 'Addison',13374,'Addison','Office Team3',5,'Jordan M','DFW','General',2,1,0,31,63,
                  73 ]]

    let SouthArlington = [ 'SouthArlington',13373,'SouthArlington','Office Team',4,'Jordan M','DFW','General',2,1,0,31,63,
                  73 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The filter you need:

```
let locationList  = data.filter(function(location){
    return emailList.some(office => office[1] === location[2]);
})
```

Here we use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
and check for every `data` if its `location` is contained in any of the offices in the array.

Another option is to create an object:

```
let result = {};
let locationList  = data.filter(function(location){
    return emailList.some(office => office[1] === location[2]);
})
locationList.forEach(loc => result[loc[2]] = loc);
```

Then `result` contains: `{Addison: Array(14), SouthArlington: Array(14)}`

Comment: Thank you, how can I seperate each office into its own data set?  What I am trying to do is to be able to email this array to that specific office email.   (programmatically)

Comment: Can you specify with an example the exact structure you wish to have in the end?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  I just updated the expected results.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you want. The current solution I wrote gives you this, but in an array. So instead of variable `let Addison`, you have it in the `[0]` cell of the array. I may have something better than array for you: see the edited answer

Comment: Yes, this is almost perfect.   how do i tackle multiple values for a certain location?  (i updated my `data` set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a map that stores the data based on location as the map key. See the comments below:

```js
let data = [
  ['Addison', 13373, 'Addison', 'Office Team', 4, 'Jordan M', 'DFW', 'General', 2, 1, 0, 31, 63, 73],
  ['SouthArlington', 13373, 'SouthArlington', 'Office Team ', 4, ' Jordan M ', ' DFW ', ' General ', 2, 1, 0, 31, 63, 73]
];

// Call Array.prototype.reduce on data
const emailByLocation = data.reduce((map, arr) => {
  const [location, ...rest] = arr;

  if (map.get(location) == null) {
    // Add a new map entry each time we encounter a new location name in
    // data. The key of the entry will be the location name (which is in
    // the first element of arr parameter) and set the value to an array 
    // that contains 1 item (i.e.: arr).
    map.set(location, [arr]);
  } else {
    // Add additional to the map entry array value for this location.
    map.get(location).push(arr);
  }

  return map;
}, new Map());

// Iterate over the map entries to see the values
emailByLocation.forEach((value, key) => {
  console.log(`[${key}] = ${value}`);
});

// Since emailByLocation is a Map, you can take advantage of that  
// and get the data for each location simply by passing the key (i.e.: the location name).
console.log('Here is the info for Addison:' + emailByLocation.get("Addison"));
console.log('Here is the info for SouthArlington:' + emailByLocation.get("SouthArlington"));
```